# Arrays.toString, no library

Tags: java, tostring

I'm going bonkers on my java assignment. I'm rather new to methods and I can't seem to get my head around this one. Could you perhaps give me a guiding hand?

I'm trying to convert an array of int to a string and print it using the.
 `toString` method. We are not allowed to use some libraries though. All I get from my code is a `'stack overflow'...`

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {3,4,5,6,7};

    String str = toString(arr);
    System.out.println("arr = " + str);
}

private static String toString(int[] arr) {
    String str = Arrays.toString(arr);
    return str;
}
```

This is the complete code of my program so far:

```
public class Arrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {3,4,5,6,7};

    int result = sum(arr);
    System.out.println(result);

    String str = toString(arr);
    System.out.println("arr = " + str);
}

private static int sum(int[] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

private static String toString(int[] arr) {
    String str = Arrays.toString(arr);
    return str;
}


}
```

The result in my console:

```
25
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at tb222kc_lab3.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:24)
  at tb222kc_lab3.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:24)
  at tb222kc_lab3.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:24).....
```

Comment: Show us your stack-overflow-producing code then? :)

Comment: [it work fine with me](https://ideone.com/oaTa03)

Comment: So the question is, are you trying to print the array with the data types as is, or are you actively trying to convert each element in the array to a specific data type?

Comment: You can take a look at `java.util.Arrays.toString(Object[])` source as an example

Comment: @xs0 I edited to show the entire code and output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I will create my own `toString` like this :

```
public String toString(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("[");
    for (int a : arr) {
        result.append(a);
    }
    result.append("]");
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you define what is a library @JamesDunn please?

Comment: Well, there may be several ways... technically java.lang is a library (but then String would count, which would be rediculous...)  StringBuilder may or may not be counted as a library, but the issue isn't me, the issue is Thomas Bengtsson's professor.  Professors are SILLY to disallow libraries, so who knows what the professor will say about StringBuilder?  I'd personally be just fine with it, but I don't know about this professor guy... that said, I like your answer so I upvoted it.

Comment: @JamesDunn then check the answer of James Dunn he don't use StringBuilder

Answer (score 8):

Change your `Arrays.toString(arr)` in `toString` Method to `java.util.Arrays.toString(arr)`

Your code has gone into recursive call because you have named your class as `Arrays`

Comment: Thanks, but that will invoke a library, no? I'm not allowed to use a library for this assignment.

Comment: @YCF_L So there is no way around that then? We got the name of the class to use...

Answer (score 1):

Your toString() method should look like this:

```
private static String toString(int[] arr) {
    String str = "[";
    for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        // Concat the string with the int value.
        str += arr[index];

        // Add delimiter only if we're not at the last index.
        if (index < arr.length - 1) {
          str += ", ";
        }
    }
    str += "]";
    return str;
}
```

I will only add to this that college professors are notorious for giving their students requirements that have no bearing on real life (like don't use libraries).

Comment: Regarding your comment - it is really hard to come up with good **and short** homework tasks that are meant to train a certain skill without restricting the library usage. Do you think the task to implement a very own LinkedList is a bad one, because there already exists an implementation? Curiously asking, since I generally agree with these kind of statements regarding teaching programming and wanted to collect more agruments from people

Comment: @Fureeish No, I don't think it's a bad one.  Actually, in spite of my jab above, it's a good assignment.  In fact, now that I take my bias hat off... :)  No, it makes sense to give an assignment like this.  In fact, if I were a professor of coding I would probably do it at first with beginning students.  It's good for people to have the skills to be able to code basic tasks.  I guess where jab comes in is, in real life work you shouldn't re-invent the wheel when someone has already written code for you.
"Collaboration in the working world is cheating in academics."  :P

Comment: I would follow that up though by saying, if I were a professor, I would emphasize that you'd *better* use libraries in real life... but for purposes of learning to program we're not going to use any for this assignment.

Comment: I completely agree, but I fear that students then come here and even if they describe the problem very well, they still get the "your professor is bad for not permitting you to use standard libraries". Anyway, I think we should cut the discussion to not off-top the comment section. Thank you for the answers!